# Is there a simply connected contact manifold, "non-exactly" fillable, cappable, such that the whole thing is symplectically aspherical?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, contact-geometry

Is there an example of a simply connected contact manifold W, with a non exact symplectic filling $M_1$, (that is, $M_1$ is a symplectic manifold, with contact boundary $W$ and a Liouville vector field defined in a neighborhood of $W$ pointing **outward**, transversally),
and a symplectic capping $M_2$,
(that is, $M_2$ is a symplectic manifold, with contact boundary $W$ and a Liouville vector field defined in a neighborhood of $W$ pointing **inward**, transversally), such that $M_1 \cup M_2$ is a symplectically aspherical manifold (that is, $\omega$ vanishes on $\pi_2$).

So far I managed to find in the literature that every symplectically aspherical filling of $(S^{2n-1},\xi_{std})$, is diffeomorphic to a ball [Eliashberg-Floer-McDuff], therefore exact, so $W$ in question must be more complicated than that.

Thanks